# passar um valor JQUERY para função window.open()

Tags: jquery

Como é que eu posso recuperar um valor que vem de uma requisição por meio de JQUERY a uma base de dados e colocar esse valor em uma função window.open();

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on("click", ".modal",  function () {
 var key  = $(this).data('numero');

 var url = 'http://www.exemplo.com&n='; 

 window.open(url, key);
});
```

Se o valor retornado foi 1000 o código deveria formar o seguinte url:

http://www.exemplo.com&n=1000

Comment: Você só quer anexar o valor na URL, isso? `var url = 'http://www.exemplo.com?n=' + key; window.open(url);`

Comment: Isso mesmo, funcionou perfeitamente aqui!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você quer anexar o valor na URL, que é apenas uma string, faça uma simples concatenação:

```
var url = 'http://www.exemplo.com?n=' + key;
window.open(url)
```

A parte do url para passar parâmetros começa com `?` e não com `&`. O `&` é para separar pares de chave/valor.